# How to get all checked checkboxes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I tried to find any solutions for this problem but I did not succeed. I only found solutions for WinForms which do not work for WPF.

I have a simple form that has some checkboxes on it. I want to know what checkboxes are checked. The only way I know to do it is to create a method for each checkbox like

```
"Checkbox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"
```

and add the name of a checkbox in a List (and remove it from list if the box is unchecked).

Is there any other way I can get all the checked checkboxes? Something like

```
foreach (var cb in this.Controls)
{
    if (cb is Checkbox && cb.IsCheked()) // blablabla
}
```

Comment: You do not have to create method for each of them. One method for all them is just enough in your case.

Comment: In WPF all components lives into others components commonly Panel (or derived components like a Grid, StackPanel, etc.) you have to get all childs of panel, and so can obtain all Checkbox into panle and validate if any is checked or not, a good solution is implement the  answer of @Shawn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use LINQ for this.
   Assuming that you named the parent control `grid`, for example.

```
var list = this.grid.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true);
```

Or, if you don't want to name it - assuming that your container derives from `Panel` (e.g `Grid`, `StackPanel`...) - simply cast it like this

```
var list = (this.Content as Panel).Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true);
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped a lot!